Why weak convergence doesn't Imply strong convergence on $\infty$- dimensional Hilbert spaces.
To start off, I know this is wrong. Im hoping someone can explain to me where Im going wrong. I know that on a finite dimensional Hilbert space that weak convergence implies strong convergence. But I have this little 'proof' in my head that keeps messing me up on infinite dimensional spaces.
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space. Then we have the property that if $\langle x,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in H$ then $x=0$.
Now, let $y_n\rightharpoonup y$ in $\mathcal{H}$ then we know $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle y_n,v\rangle=\langle y,v\rangle\text{ for all } v\in \mathcal{H}.$$ By linearity we then have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle y_n-y,v\rangle=0\text{ for all }v\in\mathcal{H}.$$
Then by continuity of the inner product (this is where I think im messing up but I may be wrong) We have, $$\langle \lim_{n\to\infty}(y_n-y),v\rangle=0 \text{ for all }v\in \mathcal{H}.$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}(y_n-y)=0$$ and so $y_n\to y \text{ as }n\to\infty$
Why does bringing that limit inside the inner product break down? Isn't the inner product continuous?
My Attempted reasoning: Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{F}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the field associated with $\mathcal{H}$.
We say $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is continuous if for each sequence $(x_n,y_n)\in\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}$ which converges to $(x,y)$ we have  $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle$ converges to $\langle y,n\rangle.$
So the definition of continuity of $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ inherently requires strong convergence, therefore I can't just pull the limit in if I only have weak convergence?
I have nobody to check my reasoning with so if anyone can help me clarify this, that would be amazing!

$\langle \lim_{n\to\infty}(y_n-y),v\rangle=0 \text{ for all }v\in \mathcal{H}$ is correct but that does not tell you that
$\lim_{n\to \infty}(y_n-y)=0$.

Take a separable Hilbert space and let $y_{n}=e_{n}$, i.e. the Hilbert basis vectors. Then Bessel's inequality tells you that $e_{n}\rightharpoonup 0$ . But does $\lim_{n\to\infty}e_{n}$ make any sense? The sequence $e_{n}$ is not even Cauchy as $||e_{n}-e_{m}||=\sqrt{2}$ for all $n\neq m$.

The weak limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n-y$ is $0$. But this does not mean anything for the existence of a norm limit.

Fix $v\in\mathcal{H}$ and let $L\colon\mathcal{H}\to\Bbb C$ be the map $L(x)=\langle x,v\rangle$. Then, what $x_n$ weakly converging to $x$ tells you is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}L(x_n-x)=0$$
And what you cannot conclude from here is
$$L\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-x)\right)=0$$
unless you know that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n-x)$ exists.
In general, continuity of $f$ tells you $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. You cannot use it the other way! (A simple counterexample is a constant function. Then, for any non convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$, you would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=c$, but that does not allow you to say anything about $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)$, because that limit may not even exist!
If you know that $x_n$ actually converges (to somewhere), then the argument indeed works.
Hope this helps. :)
